# How are non-ASCII file names encoded in RAR files?

Tags: delphi, character-encoding, file-format, rar

I have a RAR file with non ASCII letters in filenames. I tried decoding it in Delphi. My code works fine for ASCII filenames but it failed on these. It is not WideChar, nor UTF8. I found RAR specs here: 
http://ams.cern.ch/AMS/amsexch/arch/rar/technote.txt
but it says nothing about the character encoding.
I tried WOTSIT.org but all links to RARs are dead (almost every link is dead there; I even contacted admin but he didn't respond and didn't fix links).
It seems it is not an 8bit encoding, but no idea what could it be.

Comment: You can find the sourcecode for UnRAR here:
http://www.rarlab.com/rar_add.htm
It is a more uptodate version.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is the only paragraph that says something about the name:

```
0x200 - FILE_NAME contains both usual and encoded
        Unicode name separated by zero. In this case
        NAME_SIZE field is equal to the length
        of usual name plus encoded Unicode name plus 1.

        If this flag is present, but FILE_NAME does not
        contain zero bytes, it means that file name
        is encoded using UTF-8.
```

It seems that it is UTF-8, but you say it is not. Can you try again?

Comment: I tried *only* ASCII and *only* UTF-8 not *both*. I'll try this, thanks.

Comment: Thank you, @nhahtdh. I have no idea how I missed this paragraph, but indeed this flag and that 0 between ANSII and UTF-8 does the trick!